# script to automate scp in network

Tags: ssh, scripting, expect

I have a network full of Linux machines. In this network, I have a user as **user1** with the password as **password** in all the machines.

I have the following script to put files in the home directory of **user1** in all the machines of the network.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn cat /home/user1/Desktop/IPlistfile.txt | while read line do
spawn scp /home/user1/Desktop/filetobesent.txt user1@${line}:/home/user1/Desktop
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "password\r"
}
}
interact
done
```

The problem is I am getting an error message as "`can't read line. No such variable`". However, if I use a IP address directly instead of the line variable, I am able to transfer the file.

**Edit**: The IPlistfile.txt contains the list of IP addresses in my network. Each line contains a single IP address.

Comment: You might consider publishing an ssh key to the destination machine(s), and you can avoid using a script to enter a password.

Comment: Why are you not using a key instead?

Comment: It's just for a simple task. I wanted to put a instructions file inside the folder for all the users. This user is not encrypted and so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this but I highly recommend setting up passwordless `ssh` access, you'll thank me later.

### 1. Set up passwordless access to your machines.

This is by far the best method since you are bound to want to connect to the machines again and this will make your life much easier. It is also way, way safer than the other options even if you choose to use an empty passphrase since you won't be throwing passwords around unencrypted.

First, create a public `ssh` key on your machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

You will be asked for a passphrase which you will be asked to enter the **first** time you run any ssh command after each login. This means that for multiple `ssh` or `scp` commands, you will only have to enter it once. Nevertheless, you can leave it empty to have completely passwordless access.

Once you have generated your public key, copy it over (as `user1`) to each computer in your network :

```
while read ip; do 
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user1@$ip 
done < IPlistfile.txt
```

You will have to manually enter the password for each IP (unless you use one of the solutions below for this step as well) but once you've done that, you will be able to copy files to any of these machines with a simple:

```
while read ip; do
  scp /home/user1/Desktop/filetobesent.txt user1@$ip:~/Desktop
done < IPlistfile.txt
```

If you have `sshpass` installed, you can automate this so you don't need to type your password for each machine:

```
SSHPASS='password'
while read ip; do
  sshpass -e  scp /home/user1/Desktop/filetobesent.txt user1@$ip:~/Desktop
done < IPlistfile.txt
```

### 2. Install [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

This is a nifty little program that allows you to pass an `ssh` password as a command line parameter. This is, obviously, not a very secure solution and I highly recommend you read the "Security Consideretions" section of `man sshpass`.

Anyway, it is probably available in your distribution's repositories, on Debian-based systems it can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

I can't check since I don't have a RedHat based machine but as far as I can tell from searching [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/), it should be installable on Fedora with

```
sudo yum install sshpass
```

Once you have it installed, you can simply run

```
SSHPASS='password'
while read ip; do
  sshpass -e scp /home/user1/Desktop/filetobesent.txt user1@$ip:~/Desktop
done < IPlistfile.txt
```

The `-e` option tells `sshpass` to get the password from the `SSHPASS` variable. This is a bit more secure than giving it as a parameter with the `-p` option.

#### IMPORTANT:

This will fail silently if the server you are connecting to is unknown, if its public key is not stored in your machine. If this does not seem to be working, just connect once (`ssh` or `scp`) to the remote machine and accept its public key.

### 3. Use [`pscp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) instead

`pscp` is an alternative to `scp` that accepts the password as a commandline parameter. On Debian-based systems, this can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
```

As I said before, I can't check but it should be [installable](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20533837/dir/fedora_19/com/putty-0.62-4.fc19.x86_64.rpm.html) on Fedora with

```
sudo yum install putty
```

You can then copy your files with

```
while read ip; do
  pscp -pw password /home/user1/Desktop/filetobesent.txt user1@$ip:~/Desktop
done < IPlistfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using fedora based systems. I am not sure if I can use the tools like sshpass or pscp since I cannot install new packages/tools in those machines. So I think the first option would be a safer bet. But however, since this is just for a simple purpose, is there no way to enter the password in the command line itself using scp?

Comment: @Ramesh no, there is no way to do this with pure `scp` because that is a **huge security risk**, this is a feature, not a bug. Also, `sshpass` and `pscp` are both available for Fedora (see updated answer) and you only need to install them on your local machine, not the remotes. In any case, the best way is to set up passwordlss ssh, absolutely. Just install `sshpass` on your machine so you can simplify copying your key to the others (again, see updated answer).

Comment: thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.edwardawebb.com/web-development/keys-putty-cygwin-passwordless-login-ssh-scp , you have a script to make it easy in a lot of servers.