# How can I ssh to a remote server with an automated password and no key?

Tags: networking, ssh, security, remote

I have a remote server. I planned to use public keys to connect over ssh without typing the password but the remote system rejects public key authentication.

So what is the best way to do it? What about using `sshpass`?

Comment: What do you mean by "router doesn't allow it"?

Comment: @mtahmed, I tried to share public key but it fails to connect. the network administrator explained me later that the routing configuration blocks public key use.

Comment: A router cannot know whether you are using passwords or public keys for authentication. Whatever is happening, this is not the reason. Public key authentication would have to be rejected on the server itself.

Comment: @Gilles, i've just asked to the system admin of the server, and you're right. The remote ssh server rejects public key authentication. I think the network administrators just want to get rid of me !

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter/59632#59632

Comment: If I had to guess it's likely not a router but another computer that is disallowing the propagation of the forwarding of the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sshpass` if you are the only user of you system. But it's definitely a very bad idea. Everybody could get your passord if he has a shell access to your machine.

Once you can't exchange public keys. I suggest you to use `expect`. You'll need to secure an `exp` file containing your password. It will be stored on your hard disk, so every user having the sudo or root access can hack it. But at least it's really more secure than `sshpass`.

[Here's how to do it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Comment: I am the only user of my machine. ssh server is disabled. so it's the only problem with `sshpass`?

Comment: As you describe the situation you're in an enterprise network there may be some administrator who can access your machine to update your system/software/security policy. But anyway `sshpass` is a bad practice.

Comment: can i use it for file transfer?

Comment: @Nadina, Yes you can. See this [example](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/21466-automating-sftp-expect.html)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

From the link that I used as a reference, you can find more options.

If you have `sshpass` installed, you can automate the ssh connection so you don't need to type your password for each machine:

```
SSHPASS='password'
  sshpass -e  your commands here
```

### 1. Install [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

This is a nifty little program that allows you to pass an `ssh` password as a command line parameter. This is, obviously, not a very secure solution and I highly recommend you read the "Security Considerations" section of `man sshpass`.

Anyway, it is probably available in your distribution's repositories, on Debian-based systems it can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

I can't check since I don't have a RedHat based machine but as far as I can tell from searching [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/), it should be installable on Fedora with

```
sudo yum install sshpass
```

Once you have it installed, you can simply run

```
SSHPASS='password'
  sshpass -e your commands
```

The `-e` option tells `sshpass` to get the password from the `SSHPASS` variable. This is a bit more secure than giving it as a parameter with the `-p` option.

#### IMPORTANT:

This will fail silently if the server you are connecting to is unknown, if its public key is not stored in your machine. If this does not seem to be working, just connect once (`ssh` or `scp`) to the remote machine and accept its public key.

**References**

[script to automate scp in network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/script-to-automate-scp-in-network)

Answer (score 1):

As already described in other answers, I also use `sshpass` but I combine it with the `read` command to store my password in an temporary environment variable. This way my password is never written anywhere in clear. Here is the one line command I use:

```
read -s PASS; sshpass -p $PASS ssh <user>@<host adress>
```

After that you have to enter your password (nothing appears on the screen) and then pressing enter will open the connection.