# How to install software on to multiple linux clients

Tags: networking, ssh, password

Is there any free way or method for `ssh` that could be used to install and update linux clients for a ubuntu laptop. I do not have password less ssh but the admin password is the same for all of the clients. The clients are connected over WiFi and only have 512mb of ram.

Comment: Do you want to perform a single command from a origin shell?

take a look on cluster ssh.

Comment: You could refer to the canonical question as discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/script-to-automate-scp-in-network).

Comment: One of [these commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/how-can-i-reproduce-commands-run-on-one-machine-on-another-machine/14738#14738) should help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use SSH you will obviously want to setup ssh keys for passwordless entry or you will be forced to enter the password each time. SSH keys are obviously much more secure. The ssh command can be used to send a command to the remote box and then exit when the command finishes:

```
ssh root@remoteserver COMMAND
```

In your case:

```
ssh root@remoteserver [yum,apt-get,etc] install package
```

But without ssh keys you will still have to plug in the password. If you want to run several at a time, something simplet you could do is pass the servers into a for loop. BUT again without passwordless ssh you will be prompted for the password each time it connects to a server.

```
for i in remoteserver1 remoteserver2 remoteserver3; do ssh root@$i [yum,apt-get,etc] install package ; done
```

There is also a utility out there called [sshpass](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) that might be helpful for what you are looking for (never used it) but I would recommend ssh keys for simplicity and security.