# Expect script connects with ssh but does not run commands

Tags: ssh, command, expect

I need to write a script that runs on a PC with Centos 7 and connects to another PC with Centos 7 using ssh, execute a console command, for example "ls -la" and save the output of it to a file to be able to later analyze that output.

I have written the following EXPECT script:

ssh_connection.exp :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 120
spawn ssh root@129.0.0.10
expect "assword:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "prompt#"
sleep 5
puts "Executing ls -la"
send "ls -la\r"
sleep 10
puts "Executing ps -af"
puts "ps -af\r"
sleep 10
puts "Closing the ssh session\r"
send "exit\r"
```

This script connects correctly through ssh to the machine with IP = 129.0.0.10
and displays on the screen the messages that appears on "puts":
Executing ls -la
Executing ps -af
Closing the ssh session

However, it does not show the result of executing the commands I send with send:

```
ls -la
ps -af
```

What is wrong with this script?

How can I make the output of the previous commands saved in a file to be able to analyze it later with a bash script or a C program?

Comment: Just use a standard ssh command with ssh keys and a heredoc

Comment: It seems you are overcomplicating stuff. You do not need to use expect to automate stuff via ssh.

Comment: did you try a command like `spawn ssh root@129.0.0.10 ls -la>Ls`?

Comment: Run you script with `expect -d ssh_connection.exp` and see where the problems are. First thing I'd recommend is to replace all the sleeps with `expect "prompt#"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `expect` to do this. The `ssh` command can take additional arguments of commands you want to run via the SSH connection.

#### Step #1

Setup a SSH key pair (google it) and then copy the SSH key to the remote server. To do this I'd recommend using `ssh-copy-id`. See my answer to this U&L Q&A titled: [How to properly copy private keys from remote servers to my localmachine so I can connect using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453679/how-to-properly-copy-private-keys-from-remote-servers-to-my-localmachine-so-i-ca/453680#453680).

#### Step #2

Now with the ability to SSH to a server in place using a key, your above problem turns into this:

```
$ ssh root@129.0.0.10 "ls -la; ps -af"
```

You can get fancy and use [here documents (heredocs aka. here-docs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to further enhance this technique.

```
$ ssh root@129.0.0.10 <<EOF
> ls -la
> ps -af
> EOF
```

or put the commands in a file and pass them to `ssh`:

```
$ ssh root@129.0.0.10 < my.cmds
```

Comment: Why my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458801/ask-for-username-when-mounting-a-shared-drive  was marked as duplicate? I believe it's different as I want to get promoted to enter the username not just the password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I have modified my script replacing the line:

spawn ssh root@129.0.0.10

with this other, as you tell me:

spawn ssh root@129.0.0.10 "ls -la; ps -af"

Now I see the commands output on the screen and I can redirect to a file.

Next I tried to adapt this script to execute a command on another machine that is a Cisco like switch (it is not Cisco, but it is compatible).

The script with which I connect to the switch using ssh is:

**#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 120

spawn ssh user@129.0.0.50 "show vlan 500"

expect "assword:"

send "PASSWORD\r"

expect "prompt#"

sleep 5

puts "Closing the ssh session\r"

send "exit\r"**

> > >

This does not work on the switch and I get this error:

spawn ssh user@129.0.0.50 show vlan 501

user@129.0.0.50's password:

imish: invalid option -- 'c'

Try `imish --help' for more information.

send: spawn id exp6 not open

```
while executing
```

"send "exit\r""

```
(file "./ssh_script_v3.exp" line 7)
```

> > >

So I must use the expect script that send the command using "send" :

## !/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@129.0.0.50

expect "assword:"

send "user\r"

expect ">"

sleep 5

send "sh vlan 500\r"

sleep 5

send "exit\r"

> > >

Now I do not get any error, but nothing is shwon on the screen.

I have read that this happens because linux and UNIX systems automatically buffer their output when running non-interactively.
I think that Expect can make the programs think they are running interactively by means of "unbuffer", but I do not know how to use "unbuffer" with "send". My attemps to do this, do not work.